# Ajax .BeginForm returns blank view in IE9

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, internet-explorer-9, ajax.beginform

MVC4 C#

I'm using Ajax.BeginForm throughout my application and it is working great.  When I created and tested the ChkNum view it was working just fine.  Suddenly it has stopped working and I cannot figure out why.  It still works in other views but in the ChkNum view the returned page is blank (I get the header and footer but not the body) when the ModelState.IsValid test in the post action fails and the view is returned.  The proper scripts are loaded with the site and work in all other views.

ChkNum View:

```
@model ModelVM
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Title"; } 
<script type="text/javascript">
    var onSuccess = function (result) {
        if (result.url) {
            window.location.href = result.url;
        }
    }
</script>

<div id="CkNmFrm">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)    <h2>Page Title</h2>
    <span class="h5-sty">Field1: @Model.Field1  Field2: @Model.Field2</span><br />
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ChkNum", new AjaxOptions() {OnSuccess = "onSuccess", UpdateTargetId = "CkNmFrm", HttpMethod = "Post"}))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <br />
        <span class="h4-sty">Field3: </span>
        <span class="ebwid">@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Field3) </span>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Field3)<br /><br />
        <span><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></span>
        <br /><br />
    }
</div>
```

ChkNum Action:

```
public ActionResult ChkNum(int id)
{
    // code to build vM
    return View(vM);
}

[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ChkNum(ModelVM vM)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //code 
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Fix Error");
    return PartialView("ChkNum", vM);
}
```

I've gone over the code several times and compared it to working actions and views and cannot find anything amiss. I put in a breakpoint at the return PartialView and it properly stepped through the CkNmFrm.

I cannnot think of anything else that I have changed in the App that would possibly cause this problem.

At my wits end on this one.  Any help greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I'm using IE 9.
I just tried it in Chrome and the problem went away. So the question is now why does it work in several views except ChkNum and the problem is particular to IE?

Comment: You are returning `return PartialView("ChkNum", vM);` from your ActionResult, but do you have partial view with name ChkNum?. I've asked this because you didnot mention any partial view with that name. I could see ChkNum as view, but not as parital view

Comment: Not sure what you are getting at.  ChkNum is the view that I am loading as a PartialView.  Again this exact code works in several views and only fails in this particualr view and only in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem.  At the end of the view I had a large block of commented out code (@*   *@).  Right smack in the middle of that was a

```
 </div>
```

end tag that was not commented out.  When I removed it the problem cleared.  Sigh, hours wasted.  I started to delete the entire embarassing POST but have decided to leave it up in the hope others might learn from my folly.